# Ionic2: Set as root the current page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to set as root my current page after validate something, in this case, after start a service because once been started the user cannot back to the previous page until finish with the current one but if the user haven't started the service then he can still back to the previous one.

So, do you know how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this link will help you : http://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already on that page, instead of setting it as Root, you can use [Nav Guards](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-guards)

> In some cases, a developer should be able to control views leaving and
>   entering. To allow for this, NavController has the ionViewCanEnter and
>   ionViewCanLeave methods. Similar to Angular 2 route guards, but are
>   more integrated with NavController.

So we can check if the service has started but it's not finished yet, and prevent the user from leaving the page until the service is done.

To do so, we can do something like this:

```
    // Method that gets executed when the user tries to leave the page
    ionViewCanLeave() {
        if(this.serviceHasStarted && !this.serviceHasFinished) {
            let showAlertMessage = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Error',
                message: '¿You can\'t leave the page until ...',
                buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    handler: () => {

                    }
                }]
            });

            showAlertMessage.present();

            // Return false to prevent the user from leaving the page
            return false;
        } else {    
            // Return true to allow the user to leave the page      
            return true;
        }
    }
```